# Management Object Exception error on form that displays WiFi signal strength

Tags: c#, textbox, wmi, wifi

In my windows form, the application is supposed to extract the wifi signal strength and output the result into a text box.

It complies fine with no errors, but when I run it, I get a Management Exception Unhandled error, highlighting the **'in'** in the following statement :

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get()).
```

I am not sure how to edit the code to fix this problem, ultimately allowing me to display the current wifi signal strength in a text box on my form.

Code:

```
class NativeWiFi
{
    public string wifiStatus;

    public NativeWiFi() //gets signal strength
    {
       ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
       ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\WMI", "select Ndis80211ReceivedSignalStrength
       from MSNdis_80211_ReceivedSignalStrength where active=true");
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

        //output as a string 
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get()) //**PROBLEM IS HERE**
        {
            sb.Append( mo["Ndis80211ReceivedSignalStrength"]);

        }
        wifiStatus = sb.ToString();  
    }

}
```

FORM:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // on load, create timer
{          
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Interval = 2000; //2 seconds
    timer.Start();
}

//after 2 seconds, update the text box called 'wifi' to output current wifi strength

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  wifi.Text = signal.wifiStatus;
}
```

Any ideas how I can get these to work together? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post an exception message and/or stacktrace?

Comment: The message says: "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled"Index was outside the bounds of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also troubled by some problem about `WMI`. I found that WMI function can not get `Ndis80211ReceivedSignalStrength` information at  **Windows** **7** and **Windows 8**. I tried to use the WLAN SDK get the WIFI signal Quality successfully. You can refer to the below URL.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Awesome! I laid this issue to rest a while back but now when I get the time to return to it, Ill have a new approach.

Comment: I am happy for my answer can help you. Thank you for your vote.